# Converting linq to non linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-2.0

Hi i've been woeking net 2 on visual studio 2008 .net 2 and seems my linq code won't work in here. I made a few search on internet but i dont see from linq to non linq.
Here's the code ive trying to convert.

> var listWithoutCol = fmas.Select(x => new { x.NcrbNo, x.LotInfo, x.FailureMode, x.JobOwner, x.Status, x.Originator, x.DateCreated }).ToList();

The variable listWithoutCol will be used in exporting to excel.

Hope you underatand what i mean.

Comment: Just iterate over `fmas` and create the models yourself and add them to a list `listWithoutCol`?

Comment: Sorry i dont underatand what you mean.the reason of that is to select colomns only what i need

Comment: @KimIvanBay-an instead of a Select, create a List and use a `foreach( var x in fmas) { list.Add(new { x.NcrbNo, x.LotInfo, x.FailureMode, x.JobOwner, x.Status, x.Originator, x.DateCreated }) }`

Comment: A for each\for loop and create an instance of the model manually.... `new MyModel { //properties }`

Comment: @John I understood that is the point of the question, he has a linq code, and won't be able to use it as linq on his c32 project

Comment: Anonymous types are also not supported in C#2. Nor is `var`, so this is not just as simple as using `foreach`.

Comment: Its time to upgrade, stop messing around in unsupported software and frameworks.

Comment: VS 2008 includes C# 3, which supports anonymous types and `var`. OP stated .NET 2

Comment: @MichaelRandall Only if it was that easy in all work environments.

Comment: @Adriani6 Its our job to recommend and make it happen!

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yes, yes it is and it shouldn't be. We, developers see the business case from another perspective than nontechnological "Project Manager" who needs justification for spending money on something that currently "works". I've been trying to get our "dated" products moved to a newer platform for about 2 years now and... it's not happening because it "works". But that's only one reason, there could be numerous other issues obviously such as dated environments (vessels are bad for this), third party integration etc. I'm sure you know already. Rant over :)

Comment: I think var is not gonna work so how can i make the foreach loop above comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would suggest you to update to a newer version that supports linq.
But you can just create a new class:

```
class Job {
    public int NcrbNo; // use proper types.
    public int LotInfo;
    public int FailureMode;
    public int JobOwner;
    public int Status;
    public int Originator;
    public DateTime DateCreated;
}
```

Then just use a foreach to iterate.

```
List<Job> listWithoutCol = new List<Job>();
foreach (FmasType element in fmas) { // Replace FmasType with the type it is.
    Job job = new Job();
    job.NcrbNo = element.NcrbNo;
    job.LotInfo = element.Lotinfo;
    job.FailureMode = element.FailureMode;
    job.JobOwner = element.JobOwner;
    //..etc..   

    listWithoutCol.add(element);
}
```

Comment: whats the fmas type?